# Running Neural Network experiments in loop

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

I need to run neural network training with different hyper parameters settings like this:

```
for seed in range(2):
        NN_inst = FeedForwardNN(seed)
        NN_inst.load_data()
        NN_inst.classification_model()
        NN_inst.run_model()
```

First run everything works. On the second run I get tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value training/Adam/Variable_39
     [[{{node training/Adam/Variable_39/read}} = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/Variable_39"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

It looks like I need to clear tensorflow memory, but

```
K.clear_session()
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

do not help. I am using Keras, error is on fit(). 
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I using InteractiveSession() and closing it every time worked

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
#code here ...
sess.close()
```